# AS3 - MouseEvent.CLICK fires off for mouse click that happened before the listener was added

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm new to AS3 and have made a simple `"asteroids"` game with a game over screen and a `resetButton` that lets the user play again. When the user clicks on the reset button, the game over screen and the reset button are removed from the stage, and the game proper is added to the stage, along with eventListeners. One of these is a `MouseEvent.CLICK` listener added to the `stage`, which calls a `fireBullet` function. This function draws a bullet and adds it to the stage (other parts of the code then make the bullet move on the screen).

The issue that I am having is that when the user clicks on the reset button, the gameover screen is removed correctly, and the game proper (player, asteroids, eventListeners) are added to the stage correctly, but also at the same time a `bullet` fires even though the user has not clicked after clicking on the `reset button`.

My `gameOver()` function is like this:

```
stage.removeChild() all objects
stage.removeEventListener() all listeners
null out all objects

draw and add to the stage the game over text and resetButton
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onReset) to the resetButton
```

Then, the `onReset()` function looks like this:

```
stage.removeChild() the gameover text and the resetButton
call gameStart();
```

The `gameStart()` function looks like this:

```
initialize variables
draw and add player and asteroids on the screen
add eventListeners including MouseEvent.Click, fireBullet
```

I've added traces at each function to see what's going on, and this is the flow:

```
added fireBullet listener //this is gameStart() function being called from Main() and adding everything to the stage the first time
fired bullet //shooting at the asteroids
fired bullet
fired bullet
fireBullet listener should have been removed //this is gameOver() being called that removes everything from the stage and adds the resetButton
clicked on reset
added fireBullet listener //gameStart() being called again from onReset() function
fired bullet //I did not click a second time after clicking on reset
```

I've read somewhere that events are dispatched all the time regardless if any listeners are actually listening for them, so my suspicion is that my MouseEvent.CLICK listener is picking up the mouse button click from the time when the reset button is clicked, even though this listener is added to the stage afterwards.

I don't have enough experience with AS3 or programming to figure out if this is really the case and what can I do to make sure that the `MouseEvent.CLICK` listener does not respond to any clicks that happened before it was added to the stage, so any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

====

## EDIT

I was assuming I had a logic problem or didn't know something about AS3 and flash, so I just used pseudo code above. Below is a link to the full .as file including the generated .swf
And below that are the relevant functions in full
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/a4rlasq8o0taw82/wP3rB6KPKS

`private function startGame():void` this is called from Main

```
{
        //initialize variables
        bulletArray = [];
        cleanupBullets = [];
        bulletSpeed = 10;
        score = 0;

        asteroid1Speed = 0;
        asteroid2Speed = 0;
        asteroid3Speed = 0;
        asteroid4Speed = 0;

        //draw player and asteroids
        ship = drawPlayer();
        asteroid1 = drawAsteroid();
        asteroid2 = drawAsteroid();
        asteroid3 = drawAsteroid();
        asteroid4 = drawAsteroid();

        //embarrasing and inefficient code to get random number between -5 and 5 without a 0
        asteroid1Speed = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 -5);
        if (asteroid1Speed == 0)
            asteroid1Speed = returnNonZero(asteroid1Speed);

        asteroid2Speed = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 -5);
        if (asteroid2Speed == 0)
            asteroid2Speed = returnNonZero(asteroid2Speed);

        asteroid3Speed = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 -5);
        if (asteroid3Speed == 0)
            asteroid3Speed = returnNonZero(asteroid3Speed);

        asteroid4Speed = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 -5);
        if (asteroid4Speed == 0)
            asteroid4Speed = returnNonZero(asteroid4Speed);

        //trace(asteroid1Speed, asteroid2Speed, asteroid3Speed, asteroid4Speed);

        //add asteroids to stage
        stage.addChild(asteroid1);
        stage.addChild(asteroid2);
        stage.addChild(asteroid3);
        stage.addChild(asteroid4);

        //position player and add to stage
        ship.x = 40;
        ship.y = 40;

        stage.addChild(ship);

        //add event listeners
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fireBullet);
        trace("added fireBullet listener");
}
```

`private function gameOver():void` this is called from an `onFrame`(called every frame)  function that I am not including (it's too big and not exactly relevant). it's called when all asteroids are removed.

```
{
        //remove any remaining bullets off the screen
        for each (var item:Sprite in bulletArray)
        {
            stage.removeChild(item);
        }
        //null out objects and remove listeners
        bulletArray = null;
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fireBullet);
        //check if the listener has actually been removed
        if (!(stage.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK))) {
            trace("fireBullet listener should have been removed");
        }

        stage.removeChild(ship);
        ship = null

        //graphic for resetButton
        resetButton = new Sprite();
        resetButton.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
        resetButton.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 50);
        resetButton.graphics.endFill();

        //position for resetButton
        resetButton.x = 250;
        resetButton.y = 300;

        //text for resetButton
        resetTextField = new TextField();
        var resetTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        resetTextFormat.size = 30;
        resetTextFormat.color = 0x000000;
        resetTextField.defaultTextFormat = resetTextFormat;
        resetTextField.selectable = false;
        resetTextField.text = "RESET";
        resetButton.addChild(resetTextField);

        //add resetButton and listener
        stage.addChild(resetButton);
        resetButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onReset);

        //gameover text
        gameOverTxtField = new TextField();
        gameOverFormat = new TextFormat();
        gameOverFormat.size = 50;
        gameOverFormat.color = 0xFFFFFF; 
        gameOverFormat.align = "center";
        gameOverTxtField.defaultTextFormat = gameOverFormat;
        gameOverTxtField.selectable = false;
        gameOverTxtField.text = "GAME OVER";
        gameOverTxtField.width = 660;
        gameOverTxtField.height = 200;
        gameOverTxtField.x = -10;
        gameOverTxtField.y = 20;

        stage.addChild(gameOverTxtField);
}
```

`private function onReset(e:MouseEvent):void`

```
{
        trace("clicked on reset");
        //remove gameover objects and null them
        resetButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onReset);
        stage.removeChild(gameOverTxtField);
        stage.removeChild(resetButton);
        resetButton = null;
        gameOverTxtField = null;

        //restart the game
        startGame();
}
```

Comment: Please show real code, not pseudo code.

Comment: Does tracing (stage.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK)) before calling back gameStart() traces true?

Comment: I use that method with if to trace out "fireBullet listener should have been removed". I'm going to post the actual source in a minute.

Comment: +1 for editing and showing the code, it really makes a difference :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is that `MouseEvent.CLICK` is a [bubbling event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#CLICK). In Flash, events have three phases: the "capture phase", the "at target" phase, and "bubbling phase". You can read about it in this [Adobe article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/event_handling_as3.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_0).

Your reset button's click event handler happens in the "at target" phase. If you trace out the event's phase in the reset button click handler, it will show that `event.phase` is 2. Per the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventPhase.html), 1 = "capture phase", 2 = "at target", 3 = "bubbling phase".

After the reset button click handler does its work, the event then bubbles back up through the display list. Since the `stage` is at the top of the display list, the click event "bubbles up" to the stage. And by that time, you've started the game again and added the stage's click event handler. So the stage's click handler is also triggered.

You can confirm this by tracing out the value of `event.phase` in your `bulletFired()` method:

```
private function fireBullet(e:MouseEvent):void 
{ 
    // most of this time it will trace out 2 for the phase
    // except when you click on an asteroid when firing or
    // click the reset button
    trace("fired bullet, event phase: " + e.eventPhase);
    bullet = drawBullet(); 
    bullet.y = ship.y; 
    bullet.x = ship.x + (ship.width / 2); 
    bulletArray.push(bullet); 
    stage.addChild(bullet); 
}
```

To fix the problem, you can stop the event from bubbling in your `onReset()` method:

```
private function onReset(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    // prevent this event from bubbling
    e.stopPropagation();
    trace("clicked on reset"); 
    //remove gameover objects and null them 
    resetButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onReset); 
    stage.removeChild(gameOverTxtField); 
    stage.removeChild(resetButton); 
    resetButton = null; 
    gameOverTxtField = null; 
    //restart the game 
    startGame(); 
}
```

Comment: Oddly, after I attempted to answer this question (incorrectly, below) I had this very thing happen in a project I'm working on. Not sure if I can ask here but, @Sunil D, do you have any idea of the TIMING of the bubbling. You say 'by that time' the new game has been instantiated and that's why the same click tiggers the bullet. I had thought it resolves before continuing with the game (but obviously it doesn't). But how are we supposed to know how long the bubbling takes?

Comment: @moosefetcher Good question. Event bubbling will all occur within the same frame. Take a look at the `onReset()` click handler above. When I click the reset button, the current frame that Flash is rendering is interrupted by our event handler (`onReset()` in this case). `onReset()` also calls the `startGame()`, so its code is executed, adding the click listener to the `stage`. When `startGame()` finishes, Flash Player "resumes" processing the current frame... (continued in next comment)

Comment: (...continued) The `onReset()` click handler interrupted processing when the event was in the "at target" stage. Now Flash player can "resume" the event processing, meaning the event bubbles up the display list to the stage. When all of this finishes, Flash will render the next frame.  Flash gives us opportunities to cancel an event's behavior (`Event.preventDefault()`), or stop it from propagating (`Event.stopPropagation` and `Event.stopImmediatePropagation), these things wouldn't work if Flash didn't wait for our event handlers to do their thing.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the previous iteration of your game has not had the MOUSE.CLICK event listener removed. Even if the game is removed, the MOUSE.CLICK event will continue triggering whatever handler you added to it, eg; addEventListener(MOUSE.ClICK, ). When the game is removed you also need to removeEventListener(MOUSE.CLICK, ).

Comment: This is done in the gameOver function before the resetButton is added to the stage.

Comment: @GarryWong this is why I suggest showing the real code, when you don't do that you make us assume things. We get stuck on "oh it might be this obvious thing that he doesn't seem to be doing..." If there's too much code, you need to do a little debugging/investigating (like you did w/your trace statements) and try to narrow the problem down.

Comment: I tried to figure out what's going on as much as I could and narrowed it down to the flow between those three functions and the eventlisteners, so that was the only thing I had included originally. I've edited the question now with the actual code.